# Quicksort analysis problem

Tags: probability, statistics, algorithms

This is a problem from a *probability* textbook, not a CS one, if you are curious. Since I'm too lazy to retype the $\LaTeX$ I will post an ugly stitched screenshot:

[image]
[image]

This seems ridiculously hard to approach, and it doesn't help that all the difficult problems have no solutions in the textbook (the uselessly easy ones do :P ). How would I attack it?

Comment: What did you try? Is the formula to prove in (a) really *ridiculously hard to approach*?

Comment: Mainly it seems that the number of comparisons is difficult to express mathematically since the process involves an indeterminate amount of pivot selecting

Comment: Slow down, question (a) and question (a) only: obviously the RHS decomposes things according to the value of the initial pivot, right?

Comment: Offering a bounty to avoid thinking by themselves... Well, this is a strategy, aint'it?

Comment: Which textbook is this question from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is already broken into pieces in order to help you out.

a) This is the law of total expectation, using the fact that the pivot is chosen randomly.

b) Once we have a pivot, we need to split the remaining $n-1$ numbers into $2$ groups (one comparison each), and then solve the two sub-problems; one of of size $i-1$ and one of size $n-i$, respectively. The recursion comes from plugging in the result from part b to the formula from part a.

c) You can derive this from the recursion in part b.

d) Use the recursion from part c to work out what $C_{n+1}$ should be, using the fact that the harmonic sum $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{i}$ is approximately $\log (n+1)$ for large $n$.

Comment: What is $X$? It seems really unclear what exactly the difference between $X$ and $C_n$ is.

Comment: $X$ is the number of comparisons needed and $C_n$ is the expected number of comparisons needed.